# How to resample AAII weekly data to daily?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to import the following file which contains data in a weekly format (Thursdays only) and convert it to a daily file with the values from Thursday filled out through the next Wednesday skipping Saturday and Sunday.

https://www.aaii.com/files/surveys/sentiment.xls

I can import it:

```
df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Public\\Portfolio\\exports\\sentiment.xls", sheet_name = "SENTIMENT", skiprows=3, parse_dates=['Date'], date_format='%m-%d-%y')
```

Here is the result:

[image: df.info()]

But that is as far as I can get. Even the simplest resampling fails with

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'
```

I tried `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` and other methods with no incremental success.

Thoughts as to how to get this done?

Comment: Set your index to the `Date` column before you can resample: `df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)`

Comment: You can check out the `on` parameter for [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html). You can specify as `df.resample(on='Date')`

Answer (score 1):

You can try like..

```
df = pd.read_excel("sentiment.xls", sheet_name = "SENTIMENT", skiprows=3, parse_dates=['Date'], date_format='%m-%d-%y')
```

your Date column having NaN values so when you trying to convert as `datetime` it fails to do so ..

```
>>> df['Date']
0                       NaN
1       1987-06-26 00:00:00
2       1987-07-17 00:00:00
3       1987-07-24 00:00:00
4       1987-07-31 00:00:00
```

So, you to convert the datetime you need to use `coerce` to get it..

```
>>> df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')
```

Now your Date's are processed ..

```
>>> df['Date']
0             NaT
1      1987-06-26
2      1987-07-17
3      1987-07-24
4      1987-07-31
5      1987-08-07
6      1987-08-14
7      1987-08-21
```

Now Set your index to the Date column before you can resample as mention in the comments:

```
>>> df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
>>> df.head()
            Bullish  Neutral  Bearish  Total  Mov Avg  Spread   Average  +St. Dev.  - St. Dev.    High     Low   Close
Date
NaT             NaN      NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN     NaN       NaN        NaN         NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1987-06-26      NaN      NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN     NaN  0.382642   0.484295    0.280989     NaN     NaN     NaN
1987-07-17      NaN      NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN     NaN  0.382642   0.484295    0.280989  314.59  307.63  314.59
1987-07-24     0.36     0.50     0.14    1.0      NaN    0.22  0.382642   0.484295    0.280989  311.39  307.81  309.27
1987-07-31     0.26     0.48     0.26    1.0      NaN    0.00  0.382642   0.484295    0.280989  318.66  310.65  318.66
```

Comment: @John, if this answer was useful then you can upvote the answer or check mark this as an answer.

Comment: Sure, I had to trim those first three lines before so it is indeed helpful.

Comment: That is useful, even you can edit your answer which ultimately worked for you so, other can get benefitted from it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the correct answer, converts to daily, strips non-trading days and Saturday/Sunday.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay
# read csv, use SENTIMENT sheet, drop the first three rows, parse dates to datetime, index on date
df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Public\\Portfolio\\exports\\sentiment.xls", sheet_name = "SENTIMENT", skiprows=3, parse_dates=['Date'], date_format='%m-%d-%y', index_col ='Date')
df = df[3:].asfreq('D', method='ffill') # skip 3 lines then expand to daily and fill forward
df = df[df.index.map(BDay().onOffset)] # strip non-trading weekdays
df = df[df.index.dayofweek < 5] # strip Saturdays and Sundays
print(df.head(250))
```

There may be a more elegant method, but that gets the job done.